# Handling Webjob Shutdown in ServiceBusTrigger Function in Azure Webjobs SDK v3

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to gracefully handle webjob shutdown in my functions. I'm using v3 of the Azure Webjobs SDK and the Service Bus Extensions.

Here is a test function I've written, based on some sample code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Functions.cs

```
    public async Task ProcessQueueMessageAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("testqueue")] Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ILogger logWriter)
    {
        logWriter.LogError("GOT MESSAGE");
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            logWriter.LogError("Not Cancelled");
        }

        logWriter.LogError("CANCELLED!!!");           
    }
```

When I shut down the webjob, though, the cancellation doesn't get logged.

I've also tried catching a TaskCanceledException as shown in this example: https://github.com/mathewc/samples/blob/master/WebJobSamples/ContinuousJobGracefulShutdown/Functions.cs

That didn't work for me either. Any ideas how to implement this in my function?

**UPDATE (12/18/18):**

While I still haven't figured this out, I've got a workaround that suits my purposes. In my Program class, I'm declaring a `public static CancellationToken shutdownToken` variable, and setting it in my Main method to

```
shutdownToken = new WebJobsShutdownWatcher().Token;
```

Then I'm registering a callback in my function as follows:

```
Program.shutdownToken.Register(() => logWriter.LogWarning("Webjob is shutting down!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I refer to your link code and write a `WebJob` with `QueueTrigger`, then upload it and stop it after it has run a while. My output log shows it works fine. Maybe you can refer to it.

```
public static string ShutDownFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return shutDownFile;
        }
    }

    public static void ShutdownMonitorJob(
         [QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message,
         TextWriter log,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            log.WriteLine("From thread: In about 10 seconds, the job will be signaled to stop");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            // Modify the shutdown file
            File.WriteAllText(shutDownFile, string.Empty);
        })).Start();

        log.WriteLine("From function: Received a message: " + message);

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            log.WriteLine("From function: Cancelled: No");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        // Perform the graceful shutdown logic here
        log.WriteLine("From function: Cancelled: Yes");
    }
```

And this is my output log.The cancelled status is changed to yes.

```
[12/18/2018 02:14:07 > dd4ec8: INFO] From function: Cancelled: No
[12/18/2018 02:14:07 > dd4ec8: INFO] From function: Cancelled: No
[12/18/2018 02:14:07 > dd4ec8: INFO] info: Function[0]
[12/18/2018 02:14:07 > dd4ec8: INFO]       From function: Cancelled: No
[12/18/2018 02:14:07 > dd4ec8: INFO]       
[12/18/2018 02:14:09 > dd4ec8: INFO] From function: Cancelled: No
[12/18/2018 02:14:09 > dd4ec8: INFO] From function: Cancelled: No
[12/18/2018 02:14:09 > dd4ec8: INFO] info: Function[0]
[12/18/2018 02:14:09 > dd4ec8: INFO]       From function: Cancelled: No
[12/18/2018 02:14:09 > dd4ec8: INFO]       
[12/18/2018 02:14:09 > dd4ec8: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, 
refreshing 
WebJob
[12/18/2018 02:14:10 > dd4ec8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO] From function: Cancelled: Yes
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO] From function: Cancelled: Yes
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO] info: Function[0]
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO]       From function: Cancelled: Yes
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO]       
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO] Executed 'Functions.ShutdownMonitorJob' 
(Succeeded, Id=9ce21c43-c113-4794-b565-81cb615a29ab)
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO] info: Host.Results[0]
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO]       Executed 'Functions.ShutdownMonitorJob' 
(Succeeded, Id=9ce21c43-c113-4794-b565-81cb615a29ab)
[12/18/2018 02:14:11 > dd4ec8: INFO] Job host stopped
```

> I did more test with ServiceBus Trigger.

Here is my Program.cs content.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.UseServiceBus();
        JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();

    }
```

And here is my Function content.

```
private static string shutDownFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

    public static string ShutDownFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return shutDownFile;
        }
    }


    public static void ShutdownMonitorJob(
         [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue")]
         string myQueueItem,
         TextWriter log,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            log.WriteLine("From thread: In about 10 seconds, the job will be signaled to stop");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            // Modify the shutdown file
            File.WriteAllText(shutDownFile, string.Empty);
        })).Start();

        log.WriteLine("From function: Received a message: " + myQueueItem);

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            log.WriteLine("From function: Cancelled: No");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        // Perform the graceful shutdown logic here
        log.WriteLine("From function: Cancelled: Yes");
    }

}
```

And this my new log pic.[image]

I stopped the `webjob` and the status change normally.

Comment: I’m using a ServiceBusTrigger, and it’s not working for me. I realize the example was for QueueTrigger but haven’t been able to find a sample specific to ServiceBusTrigger.

Comment: @Brian Campbell I update my answer, I test the ServiceBus Trigger.It's OK for me.

Comment: Thank you George. It is still not working for me. I copied your exact function method into my code too. A couple of things to note: my webjob is a .NET core application and I'm using v3.0.3 of the webjobs SDK. The job hosting model is different from the version you're using, so perhaps that is part of the issue. I'm going to submit this as a Github issue to the webjobs team and see if there is any more information they have. In the meantime, I'll just continue to use my workaround.